# POJO to Map without JSON string in between

Tags: java, json, gson

Does Gson allow one to write an equivalent of this:

```
Gson gson = ...; //build gson with custom type adapters
gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(pojo), Map.class);
```

without the overhead of turning everything into a `String` first?

In other words, I need the equivalent of this Jackson-using line:

```
objectMapper.convertValue(pojo, Map.class)
```

I am aware this can be done using other libraries or just reflection, but the reason to use Gson specifically is because the conversion needs to obey the same custom logic that the `gson` object is already configured with via extra type adapters. Using any other library would mean duplicating this logic.

Comment: Do you need it to be a `Map`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The result? Yes. I realize there's a billion ways to achieve this, but I'm asking specifically if there's an easy one using Gson.

Comment: Would the down-voter mind explaining their reasoning?

Comment: Isn't `convertValue` also doing the [same] (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class) )? I mean convert to json and then back to object Type from json? PS : I didn't downvote.

Comment: @BandiKishore Not exactly. It does convert to an intermediary representation (and back), but not into a _string_. The key part from JavaDoc is `may be executed without fully serializing into JSON`. Btw, I found my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the way to do it:

```
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(pojo);
return gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Map.class);
```

This will respect the custom conversion logic configured in `gson`, but will not stringify the intermediary representation.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference with using `toJsonTree` and `toJson`. I tested this with a sample example and the output was the same, maybe it has something to do with the internal working. Any reason on how they're different and why you choose toJsonTree over simple string based toJson?

Comment: @BandiKishore The results _should_ always be identical. The difference is only in the number of steps needed. Turning the original value into `JsonElement` needs to happen anyway, but serializing everything into a string in this case does not, and using `toJsonTree` is a way to avoid it (by only working with `JsonElement`).

Comment: hmm, I didn't know there was a better way to do this. I had to create a deep copy of an object once and used toJson and fromJson. (If only I knew there was a better way). I'll go through the source code once. Thanks :)